# Change Set variable in CMAKE depending on type of development machine

Tags: cmake

I am developing program for Raspberry Pi Pico. I am using Raspberry Pi Pico C/C++ SDK which uses cmake to build project.

I am developing the program on both Windows machine and on Raspberry Pi 4 (Linux).

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I wish to programmatically switch the `PICO_SDK_PATH` depending on type of machine I am using.

Windows Path

```
set(PICO_SDK_PATH "C:/Pico/pico-sdk")
```

Linux (Raspbian on raspberry Pi 4) Path

```
set(PICO_SDK_PATH "/home/xxx/Pico/pico-sdk")
```

I wish to do something like

```
#ifdef _Windows //depening on development machine
   set(PICO_SDK_PATH "C:/Pico/pico-sdk")
#else
   set(PICO_SDK_PATH "/home/xxx/Pico/pico-sdk")
```

How can I achieve the same.

Comment: Not familiat with this pico sdk, but depending on the functionality it provides a find/package configuration script could be appropriate (to allow using `find_package` to locate the files). Maybe those files even exist already. Usually hardcoding paths that are not part of your project is not a good idea: If you ever want to build the project on a machine where the sdk is installed at `/home/yyy/Pico/pico-sdk` you cannot do so without modifying your project. I recommend passing this kind of option via `-D` option during cmake configuration (or preferably going with the cmake config script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the `WIN32` CMake variable is defined. You can use something like the following to set the variable:

```
if(WIN32)
  set(PICO_SDK_PATH "C:/Pico/pico-sdk")
else()
  set(PICO_SDK_PATH "/home/xxx/Pico/pico-sdk")
endif()
```

Comment: This does exactly what the op asked for but ignores the fact that hardcoding those paths severely limits the scenarios where this project can be used: The sdk needs to be installed in a specific location and on linux you may not even have the permissions to create `/home/xxx`...

Comment: @fabian What is the alternative to hardcoding these paths in cmake?

Comment: Passing the info in via cache variable during configuration or possibly even using `find_package`... If there"s a standard set of machines you're working with the values could be hardcoded into `CMakeUserPresets.json`.